# Canvas Game: My snake eats itself

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, coffeescript

Since my other bug got solved, I'm posting a new question for this bug.

I made a Snake canvas game, but my snake tends to eat itself when you press two buttons at the same time.. I'm not sure how to explain it properly, but this is what happens:

Say my snake is moving towards the left, and I press down + right, it'll eat itself and trigger a game over. Same when it goes to the right: down + left and bam, dead. I can't seem to reproduce the bug when the snake goes up and down though..

This is the code involved with changing directions:

```
bindEvents = ->
    keysToDirections =
        37 : LEFT
        38 : UP
        39 : RIGHT
        40 : DOWN

    $(document).keydown (e) -> 
        key = e.which
        newDirection = keysToDirections[key]

        if newDirection
            setDirection newDirection
            e.preventDefault()

setDirection = (newDirection) ->
    # TODO: there's some bug here; try pressing two buttons at the same time..
    switch Snake.direction
        when UP, DOWN
            allowedDirections = [LEFT, RIGHT]
        when LEFT, RIGHT
            allowedDirections = [UP, DOWN]

    if allowedDirections.indexOf(newDirection) > -1
        Snake.direction = newDirection
```

I thought there was something wrong with the compiled JS because my switch statement doesn't have a `break` on the last `case`; however, I tried adding `else return` to the coffee script file and this didn't change anything. I'm completely lost here so I hope someone will be able to spot where I'm going wrong.

It seems as if it takes the keydown events right, but they get overridden when you press too fast. If that makes sense? Like.. You'd press up when the snake is going right, but then you press left before it actually had a chance to go up and then it just goes left. Chaotic sentence right there, I suggest you play for a while and try to reproduce this if you're as intrigued as I am :(

I have no clue how to debug this properly.. The game loop tends to spam me with messages when I do `console.log`.

A live demo and link to my github repo can be found [here](http://jorisooms.be/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that if you push the keys quickly enough, its possible to trigger the event callback multiple times during one frame.  Thus, if the snake is going down, it can turn right and then up in the same frame, thus reversing direction and eating itself.  I'll suggest two ways to solve this problem:

The first is to set a flag when the direction is changed, i.e.:

```
if allowedDirections.indexOf(newDirection) > -1 and !turnedThisFrame
    Snake.direction = newDirection
    turnedThisFrame = true
```

and then, in your code that runs every frame, set `turnedThisFrame` to `false`.

The second is to rework how you deal with keypresses.  This is often the approach that I take.  Keep a map of which keys are pressed (say, `keysDown`), and bind a function that sets `keysDown[e.which] = true` to keydown and another function which sets `keysDown[e.which] = false` to keyup.  Then, you can check which keys are pressed in the code that runs each frame, and act accordingly.

Here's some details on how I implemented the second solution in a current project.  The following code appears in my onload handler:

```
do ->
  keysDown = []

  $(document).keydown (e) ->
    keysDown.push e.which

  $(document).keyup (e) ->
    keysDown = _.without keysDown, e.which

  window.isPressed = (keyCode) -> keyCode in keysDown
```

The `do ->` construct is used to create a function and immediately calling it, which has the beneficial effect of keeping `keysDown` in closure for the handlers and `isPressed`, while avoiding polluting the main scope of the `onload` callback.

Then, at the beginning of my `tick` function (which runs once per frame and handles game logic, drawing the screen, etc.) I would have something like this:

```
switch Snake.direction
    when UP, DOWN
        allowedDirections = [LEFT, RIGHT]
    when LEFT, RIGHT
        allowedDirections = [UP, DOWN]

for direction in allowedDirections
    if isPressed(directionToKey[direction])
        Snake.direction = newDirection
        break
```

The map `directionToKey` would just be the opposite of your `keysToDirections`.

Note that this means that keys listed first in `allowedDirections` will have priority, i.e. if you are going right and press both up and down in the same frame, up will occur regardless of which was pressed first.

Added advantage to this second method: you don't have to change the key handler callbacks when switching between, say, a menu screen and the game.  You just have a different `tick` function checking for what is pressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I put in the first solution at the moment but I will definitely check out the second way once I wrap my head around it. I'd have to rewrite my code to do that, I think. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I gave more details on how to implement the second method.  Its really not too much work to change it, and I prefer it for the reasons stated in my post.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll definitely take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

You must retain the last direction is which the snake actually moved and determine allowedDirection based on that. Pressing a key only represents the intent to move in that direction, but it does not actually move when the key is pressed, but based on the speed of the game, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your snake eating itself shows a problem with your hit detection (and hit detection handling) code. If you're hitting the snake, the game should end. A snake is not an apple!</strike> Nevermind, apparently I missed the part where the game *is* ending for you.

If you choose to allow pixel-granularity (I can't see your demo, my work's network is half-down..), you can't really make U turns "safe", like you could with a hex-granularity approach. Not saying your choice is bad, just telling you to pick your battles, some you just can't win.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved it by implementing a queue; each keypress sets the direction of the snake and that (new) direction is pushed to an array. Then, before I actually move the snake in the game loop, I check if there are any elements in my direction queue. If so, I shift it once via Array.shift. The return value is the first element of the queue and the new direction for my snake. Array.shift also removes that element from the queue, which is exactly what we want. If two keys are pressed almost simultaneously, the first and the second direction change is stored in our queue, and our aforementioned routine takes care of the rest, by first applying the first direction change in the next available tick and then applying the second direction change in the next tick thereafter.

Hope that makes sense? :-)